# Go through each letter in the string and checks if it is a delimiter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need help with my task, there is a function which checks string letters. I tried with `for` and `foreach` loop but it didn't help :(

```
  let value = this.tagsForm.controls["tagInput"].value;

  let valueArray: [];

  for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    if(value.charAt(i) != ", || ; || /") {
      valueArray = value.charAt(i);
      alert(valueArray);
    } else {
      alert('error');
    }
  }
}
```

I must go through each letter in the string which I get from form control in angular And check if it is a delimiter, it must cut everything before the current position and put into an array.

the delimiter can be either comma, semicolon or a newline
any help guys I would be very thankful.

Comment: You are comparing a String `, || ; || /` to a single character ( `charAt(i)` in your array.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the value by the delimiter and take the chunks as a new array
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

Use the split function

```
string.split(',');
```

here the [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_string_split.htm)

You could split and then loop on the result to check if there are other delimiter occurrences